# When data updated change the color of font

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Json file and with jquery I display it and data can update without refreshing the page.
I doubt I can do this.

When the data is updated I want to change the color of data. In bitcoin part I fetch the json file and I want to change this div's color
.
How can I do that?

```html
...

<!-- Bitcoin part -->

<div style="height: 500px">
    <!-- just to make scrolling effect possible -->
    <h2 class="myH2" style="padding-bottom: 50px;">Bitcoin</h2>
    <div  class="text-center" id="myData" style="margin-left:500px; font-weight: bold; color: indianred;"></div>
    </div>
<!-- Bitcoin part ends -->





...

<!-- Function used to display json file -->
<script>
    fetch("currentprice.json")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(appendData)
        .catch(console.error);

    function appendData(data) {
        const dataFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (const price of Object.values(data.bpi)) {
            dataFragment.appendChild(createPriceElement(price));
        }
        document.getElementById("myData").appendChild(dataFragment);
    }

    function createPriceElement(price) {
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = `<table><tr><th>Code&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</th><th>Symbol&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</th><th>Rate</th><th>Description&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</th><th>Rate float</th></tr><tr>
            <td> ${price.code} &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <td>   ${price.symbol}&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<td>  ${price.rate}&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</td><td>  ${price.description} </td><td> ${price.rate_float}</td>
        </tr></table> <br><br>` ;

        return div;
    }


    setInterval(function(){
        reload() // this will run after every 5 seconds
    }, 5000);
</script>
<footer style="text-align: center; padding: 3px;background-color: crimson;  color: white;">
E...
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is taken.

Comment: Color? What color? (Offtopic, it should be `&nbsp;` with `;` Actually, you should use CSS. Also, as well as you should not use inline `on*=""` handlers, which hopefully you don't - avoid using inline `style=""` attributes.)

Answer (score -1):

Also your question is not clear but I try my best.

in order to change color of an element in javascript use this code.

```
document.getElementById("elementId").style.color = "blue";
```

so use it this way

```
<h1 id="elementId" onclick="change_color()">hello</h1>

<script>
function change_color(){
   document.getElementById("elementId").style.color = "blue";
}
</script>
```

Comment: 1. As well as you would not (hopefully) suggest to use inline `style=""` don't suggest to use hardly debuggably inline `on*=""` handlers. This is not w3schools. 2. The click event has nothing to do with the Question. 3. styles (usually) should be handled and defined in CSS. JS should only the one that eventually toggles / changes a className. 4. Your example makes no sense, you're limiting yourself to one element only. 5. OP is asking to change color once the data updates...